# Xampp Cannot load C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am posting this question because the answers that are on this site are more than 5 years ago and none of the suggestions work. This seems like something that should not be happening now but it is. It is a windows server 2008 and it had a previous version of Xampp running before I downloaded the latest 7.2.28.
Which is running the PHP5.x. I check the config of the old program and it looks just like the new one.  IIS is not running.

The whole error message.

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 537 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified procedure could not be found.     .

Yes, I have gone to the folder and the file does exist. I have checked the path and added C:/ in front of the path to the directories and no change.

I have checked the Visual Studio installs with the httpd.exe -v. I installed the latest versions anyway and rebooted the server and still get the same error. MySQL starts up just fine.

Is there something wrong with the environment variable?

```
   #
   # XAMPP settings
   #

<IfModule env_module>
SetEnv MIBDIRS "/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>
```

Here are the lines in question and the changes I made to them.

```
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

If I comment out the LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll then the next line does not load either.

Should I put a path statement in the windows environment settings?

I ran the setup_xampp.bat file and this these are the results of that and the test_php.bat file.

```
################################# START XAMPP TEST SECTION #####################
############
[XAMPP]: Test php.exe with php\php.exe -n -d output_buffering=0 --version ...
[XAMPP]: Test for the php.exe successfully passed. Good!
################################# END XAMPP TEST SECTION #######################
############


################################# START XAMPP TEST SECTION #####################
############


[XAMPP]: FIRST TEST - Searching for an installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 runti
me package in the registry ...

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\Runti
meMinimum
    Version    REG_SZ    14.0.24123

[SUCCESS]: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package found! Good!


[XAMPP]: SECOND TEST - Execute php.exe with php\php.exe -n -d output_buffering=0
 --version ...

[SUCCESS]: Test for the php.exe successfully passed. Good!

################################# END XAMPP TEST SECTION #######################
###########
```

Comment: The answer is Windows Server 2008 is no longer supported by PHP 7.2.x. Need to upgrade the OS or switch to any favor of Linux you like and this problem goes away.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 x64 and also have this problem.